# New instance registering with ELB too soon, how can CI signal if instance provisioning was successful?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudformation

I am using CloudFormation template that creates launch configuration and auto scaling group. User data script for this launch configuration calls CI web-hook to deploy application into this instance. Naturally web-hook responds with 200 immediately, but deployment process will take 2-3 minutes. If I call `cfn-signal` immediately, instance will register with load balancer too soon, so how can I postpone it? Ideally I think CI should signal if app deployment was successful or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to trigger CloudFormation resource creation completion from a CI process outside of the launched EC2 instance without calling `cfn-signal` from the instance, you can just signal using the [SignalResource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_SignalResource.html) API call, either directly or via any of the AWS SDKs (e.g., [`aws cloudformation signal-resource`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/signal-resource.html) from the CLI, [`cloudformation.signalResource`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFormation.html#signalResource-property) from the NodeJS SDK possibly via a Lambda function, etc.

Just make sure to use the instance ID that you are signaling as the 'unique ID'.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for.